# Drupal.behaviors, attach and origin of it

Tags: 8, javascript

The structure of `Drupal.behaviors` is rather similar in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8. Where do `attach()` and `detach()` come from?
Thid code is from drupal.js , still wondering where attach method in this.attach is defined?

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors = function (context, settings) {
  context = context || document;
  settings = settings || Drupal.settings;
  // Execute all of them.
  $.each(Drupal.behaviors, function () {
    if ($.isFunction(this.attach)) {
      this.attach(context, settings);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attach() and detach() methods are part of the Behaviors interface defined by Drupal:

> Any object defined as a property of Drupal.behaviors will get its
>   attach() method called when the DOM has loaded both initially and
>   after any AJAX calls.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: Thanx. I see that I didnt have good understanding of JS and declaring methods, I was thinking this was some already declared method like http://api.jquery.com/append/ that I can use on elements, objects. I dig a bit deeper and saw what is what.